# Как экстренно завершить void метод?

Tags: java

Как можно завершить работу метода, если он ничего не возвращает?

```
Например:
void method(array[][]){
if(array==null) завершить работу
\*
рабочий код
*\
}
```

Comment: `return;` наверно так.

Comment: Подобный код похож на проверку pre-conditions. Соответственно, возможно и не нужно завершать, а лучше выбросить, например, IllegalArgumentException...
Ведь если задуматься, то где-то в программе мы вызываем этот void метод и потом не знаем, отработал он или был досрочно завершен. Может, и есть такие задачи, но мне кажется, это изначально неправильный подход.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте `return;`

```
void method(int[][] array) {
    if(array == null) {
        return;
    } else 
         ...
    }
}
```

Или просто:

```
void method(int[][] array) {
    if(array == null)
        return;
    ...
}
```

PS. ar**r**ay.

Comment: В первом варианте `return` не нужен, можно оставить пустую ветвь `if`, а тогда уж лучше инвертировать условие и оставить только одну ветвь.

Comment: @Roman, Вопрос был поставлен весьма точно: «Как экстренно завершить void метод?», ровно на него я и ответил, а «как правильнее организовать работу метода» – это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Тогда зачем вы вообще привели первый вариант? С точки зрения _вопроса_, первый вариант дублирует второй.

Comment: @Roman, Дабы показать, что можно еще и так (но это вовсе не значит, что это лучший вариант).